# Best way to store a count attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to fetch all users not currently in an active match by:

```
User.where("id <> ? and active_matches = 0", user.id).limit(1).order("RANDOM()")
```

This way, I have to update the active_matches attribute of my User entity each time a User creates a match. I also have a join table matches_users and I wonder if I could utilize this to get the number of active matches for each User?

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
before_destroy { users.clear } 

# Associations
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
belongs_to :user

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

# Associations
has_and_belongs_to_many :matches


class CreateMatches < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :matches do |t|
      t.integer :user_1
      t.integer :user_2
      t.boolean :active
      t.integer :winner

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateMatchesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :matches_users, :id => false do |t|
        t.integer :user_id
        t.integer :match_id

    end
  end
end


create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "credit",                 default: 0
t.integer  "active_matches",         default: 0
```

end

Comment: Could you provide info on the relationship between `User` and `Match`, including the relevant schema attributes of the models and the join table?

Answer (score 0):

How about an association scope?

```
class User
  has_many :active_matches, -> { where status: "active" }, class_name: "Match"
end
```

Basically what happens is you select the matches where status is active, so you can do `User.where(1).active_matches.count`. You probably have to tweak it some for the HABTM (has_and_belongs_to_many). I recommend `has_many :through` though, for the reasons, check this article out: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/2/28/association-goodness.